# How to determine the remaining roots when two distinct real roots and y-intercept are given

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

A quartic polynomial has 2 distinct real roots at $x=1$ and $x=-3/5$. If the function has a y-intercept at -1 and has $f(2)=2$ and $f(3)=3$, determine the remaining roots and produce an accurate sketch of the function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: you can sum up everything you know in a system like this:
\begin{cases}
f(1)=0\\
f(-\frac35)=0\\
f(0) = -1\\
f(2) =2\\
f(3) = 3\\
\end{cases}
Then it's very simple to find all the coefficients of $f(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, because you have a 5-variable system and 5 equations, so the solution is unique! For example, from the 3rd equation we get $f(0) = 0+0+0+0+e=-1 \Rightarrow e=-1$, and so on. After some calculus we obtain: 
\begin{cases}
a=\frac{5}{156}\\
b=-\frac{41}{78}\\
c=\frac{289}{156}\\
d=-\frac{14}{39}\\
e=-1\\
\end{cases}
Finally we manage to find the polynomail, and the associated function: $$f(x) = \frac{5}{156}x^4 -\frac{41}{78}x^3+\frac{289}{156}x^2-\frac{14}{39}x-1$$
So all the real roots are $x_1= -\frac35,x_2= 1,x_3 = 8-2\sqrt{3},x_4= 8+2\sqrt{3}$. Eventually we can sketch a graph of the function: [image]

Comment: Even easier, use the statement about roots to write it as $y=x(x-1)(ax^2+bx+c)$  Now only three parameters to determine, but the same idea.

Comment: I think it's $y=(x-1)(x+\frac35)(ax^2+bx+c)$, the real root is -$\frac35$...

Comment: In between us:  it should be $(x-1)(x+\frac 35)(ax^2+bx+c)=0$